# Parse channel set to 'undefined' in Installation Objects

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm currently working on an Android-App and my task was to integrate Push-functionality with Parse.

When the user launches the app for the first time, he subscribes to the broadcast-channel by default.

```
if (!push_firstTime) {
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
              @Override
              public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    pushFirstTimePreferences.edit().putBoolean("push_enable", true).commit();
                    pushFirstTimePreferences.edit().putBoolean("push_firsttime", false).commit();
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                  Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
              }
            });
    }
```

But when I look at the Installation-Objects in the Parse Dashboard, I can see, that almost all channels are set to `(undefined)` and just about 5-10% of all objects have `[""]`, respectively `[]` after unsubscribing.

Why is the majority of the channels set to `(undefined)`?

Any help is welcome! Thanks

Comment: Jon_m is solved your problem? if yes please help me to solve this issue for my android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have the same problem. Yesterday only 3 of 15 installations had a correct channel instead of undefined. Today this number has increased to 4. Maybe it is caused by app installs vs app runs? Automatic updates would install the app but not run it. Device registration could be part of an Android service (started automatically by the OS), while channel registration part of an activity (started manually by the user).

I'm also very interested if you happen to have solved this issue.

Comment: Yes, I have same problem. Channel is to (undefined) for more users. How to solve this issue? For min records its channel name is set correctly.

Comment: Most of them have been filled in by now. New records sometimes still have undefined but all the 15 installations I mentioned above in my answer are OK now. My best guess is still that is has something to do with installation versus actual usage of the app.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for my late answer. As far as i can remember it is exactly like you described it. I think the channel is set when the user opens the app, if he just installs it the channel is still undefined. 
After finding no answer i just deployed the app and it seems to run fine, no user complained about missing notifications.

Comment: If my answer could help other people in the same situation please mark it as such so it's clear they just have to wait a little before the channels are all set.